# Error in installing cordove

Tags: cordova, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install cordova in Ubuntu with

```
npm install -g cordova
```

But it shows an error as

```
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/user/project/npm-debug.log
```

How to solve this? I googled it a lot and cant find an appropriate solution. Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Just guessing:`npm -g` tries to install globally. Does `sudo npm install -g cordova` work?

Comment: but i want it to install globally.

Comment: Perhaps a permission problem. Try calling with `sudo`. Does it work?

Comment: If this won't work, you should post the relevant part of `npm-debug.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing using 'sudo' permission and then change the access permission of your .config folder to 755,

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

for changing permission try,

```
sudo chmod -R 755 <dir name>
```

in most of the versions .config will be located in 
'/home//.config'